# Juju Subordinate Charm: Vault mysql-router

Tags: juju, maas, openstack

I'm trying to deploy charmed Openstack inside my Juju managed MAAS environment (following deployment guide from Openstack website), but I can't deal with one thing.
I'm having a problem with deployment of mysql-router for Vault charm. The last message before execution loops is:

> Hook failed: "install"

Aside from that, when I execute "juju debug-log" I get python error like the one below:

```
unit-vault-mysql-router-2: 12:24:07 ERROR unit.vault-mysql-router/2.juju-log Hook error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/juju/agents/unit-vault-mysql-router-2/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/charms/reactive/__init__.py", line 74, in main
    bus.dispatch(restricted=restricted_mode)
  File "/var/lib/juju/agents/unit-vault-mysql-router-2/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/charms/reactive/bus.py", line 390, in dispatch
    _invoke(other_handlers)
  File "/var/lib/juju/agents/unit-vault-mysql-router-2/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/charms/reactive/bus.py", line 359, in _invoke
    handler.invoke()
  File "/var/lib/juju/agents/unit-vault-mysql-router-2/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/charms/reactive/bus.py", line 181, in invoke
    self._action(*args)
  File "/var/lib/juju/agents/unit-vault-mysql-router-2/charm/reactive/layer_openstack.py", line 26, in default_install
    instance.install()
  File "lib/charm/openstack/mysql_router.py", line 224, in install
    super().install()
  File "/var/lib/juju/agents/unit-vault-mysql-router-2/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/charms_openstack/charm/core.py", line 638, in install
    fetch.apt_install(packages, fatal=True)
  File "/var/lib/juju/agents/unit-vault-mysql-router-2/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/charmhelpers/fetch/ubuntu.py", line 284, in apt_install
    _run_apt_command(cmd, fatal)
  File "/var/lib/juju/agents/unit-vault-mysql-router-2/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/charmhelpers/fetch/ubuntu.py", line 778, in _run_apt_command
    retry_message="Couldn't acquire DPKG lock")
  File "/var/lib/juju/agents/unit-vault-mysql-router-2/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/charmhelpers/fetch/ubuntu.py", line 756, in _run_with_retries
    result = subprocess.check_call(cmd, env=env)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 311, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['apt-get', '--assume-yes', '--option=Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold', 'install', 'mysql-router']' returned non-zero exit status 100.

unit-vault-mysql-router-2: 12:24:07 ERROR juju.worker.uniter.operation hook "install" (via explicit, bespoke hook script) failed: exit status 1
```

Since I'm fairly new to Juju stuff, I don't know what else I could do to troubleshoot this.
All hosts in my MAAS cloud are Ubuntu 18.04, except for LXD containers which somehow deploy as Focal (20.04).

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled today upon the same problem. I was following this tutorial: https://docs.openstack.org/project-deploy-guide/charm-deployment-guide/latest/install-openstack.html. When I looked into the logs in the /var/log/juju directory on the vault-mysql-router/0 machine (juju ssh vault-mysql-router/0) I saw that there was no package candidate in the repository. My guess is that juju by default deploys bionic ubuntu, for chich mysql-router is not available (https://jaas.ai/mysql-router shows some other series but not bionic).

I restarted the whole installation by destroying the controller and bootstrapping it using --bootstrap-series focal switch. Later on for each deploy I added --series focal which deployed all the charms using the newest Ubuntu LTS. For that the mysql-router installed correctly. This also solves the problem where some LXD containers had focal series whereas rest had bionic (which is no good according to the documentation).

I do not know however if whole installation will work. I'm in the middle so far (after the RabbitMQ step) and so far it looks good. I had to follow the steps described in https://docs.openstack.org/project-deploy-guide/charm-deployment-guide/latest/app-certificate-management.html to generate self signed CA certificate and reissue them as ovn didn't want to get one even thou the vault was unlocked and keystone got its certificate.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'll definitely try this out. My Juju deployed Bionic as well, except for LXD containers which turned out to be Focal, so maybe there lies the problem with mysql-router.